# How to fix problems with Mono

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I try to run my asp.net webforms aplication but I got an issue with MsAjaxBundle, my server is ubuntu 16.04 and I'm using Mono

I got this message:
Assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not contain a Web resource with name 'MsAjaxBundle'.
Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Web.Extensions.

> Exception stack trace:
>     at System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceBase.VerifyAssemblyContainsResource (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.String resourceName, System.Web.UI.WebResourceAttribute& wra) [0x00074] in :0 
>     at System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceBase.GetScriptName (System.String releaseName, System.Boolean isDebugMode, System.String[] supportedUICultures, System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Web.UI.WebResourceAttribute& wra) [0x00009] in :0 
>     at System.Web.UI.ScriptReference.GetUrl (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager scriptManager, System.Boolean zip) [0x00028] in :0 
>     at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterScriptReference (System.Web.UI.Control control, System.Web.UI.ScriptReferenceBase script, System.Boolean loadScriptsBeforeUI) [0x00012] in :0 
>     at System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.OnPreRenderComplete (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x002c8] in :0 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.OnPreRenderComplete (System.EventArgs e) [0x00024] in <3e7f5ad0056f4fcd8a164c7d821f158c>:0 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessLoadComplete () [0x000b7] in <3e7f5ad0056f4fcd8a164c7d821f158c>:0 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () [0x001ad] in <3e7f5ad0056f4fcd8a164c7d821f158c>:0 
>     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x0005f] in <3e7f5ad0056f4fcd8a164c7d821f158c>:0

Comment: Is it possible you have referenced a windows assembly in your Linux project? Is there a reason you aren't using dot net core which supports both platforms natively.?

Comment: Im not sure but I think dot net core doesn't work with webForms, Im using nginx and fastcgi-mono-server4